# How to check if a package is installed in android Kotlin programmatically for android 12+?

Tags: android, kotlin

To Check if a package is installed in android Kotlin programmatically for android 12+. Without declaring a query in the manifest file for Android 12+(API 31+).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private fun isAvailable(ctx: Context, intent: Intent?): Boolean {
    val mgr = ctx.packageManager
    val list = mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent!!, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
    return list.size > 0
}
```

Use this code snippet for that, Thanks.

Comment: That requires "declaring a query in the manifest file for Android 12+(API 31+)", which is what the question specifically blocks. Without `<queries>`, you will have access to some packages, not all.

Comment: Actually, this specific function doesn't require anything to be declared in Manifest and does the job.

Comment: I covered package visibility fairly extensively in [this free book](https://commonsware.com/R). Here is [the relevant section](https://commonsware.com/R/pages/chap-package-005). With a `targetSdkVersion` of `30`, nothing in `<queries>`, and without `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission, you only see pre-installed apps. It is possible they changed things in later Android versions, but that should be all you get on Android 11.